# CodeIgniter many to many relationship

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

How I can setup many-to-many relationship in ActiveRecord CodeIgniter model?
Like RoR has_many, :through => 'table1_table2'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CodeIgniter doesn't have a built-in ORM. You would have to build it from scratch or use something like Doctrine. If you use an external ORM library (like Doctrine), you'd have to check their documentation about how to do n:m relationships.